# sum through specific values in an array

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I have an array of data-points, for example:

[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

and I need to perform the following sum on the values:

[image]

However, the problem is that I need to perform this sum on each value > i. For example, using the last 3 values in the set the sum would be:

[image]

and so on up to 10. 
If i run something like:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
alpha = 1/np.log(2) 

for i in x:
    y = sum(x**(alpha)*np.log(x))
print (y)
```

It returns a single value of y = 247.7827060452275, whereas I need an array of values. I think I need to reverse the order of the data to achieve what I want but I'm having trouble visualising the problem (hope I explained it properly) as a whole so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just get rid of the `for` loop and the `sum`. It's simply `y = x**(alpha)*np.log(x)` or perhaps `y = x**(alpha)*np.log(x).cumsum()`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had already tried that but it seems I decided to just overcomplicate things!

Comment: Why do you need/expect an array of output values? You are summing over `x`, a one-dimensional array, and thus you end up with a scalar. Is the formula written incorrectly? Should `i=1` be a variable instead, like `i=j`, and `j` runs from 1 to 10? That is what I gather from your example code.

Comment: @roganjosh - why not make an answer of your comment?

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I'm not convinced that it adds anything to the SO repository of knowledge since it fixes a single case that isn't expressed clearly in a title. Feel free to take the approach in my comment and post as an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following computes all the partial sums of the grand sum in your formula

```
import numpy as np

# Generate numpy array [1, 10]
x = np.arange(1, 11)
alpha = 1 / np.log(2)
# Compute parts of the sum
parts = x ** alpha * np.log(x)
# Compute all partial sums
part_sums = np.cumsum(parts)
print(part_sums)
```

You really do not any explicit loop, or a non-`numpy` operation (like `sum()`) here. `numpy` takes care of all your needs.